# ¿Recibir un objeto como parámetro de un método y obtener sus atributos?

Tags: java

Estoy implementando un MVC en un programa de tiene varios objetos.
Tengo definida una Interface con un metodo que recibe un objeto **X que esta definido**:

```
public interface Interface {
    public void escribir(Object  objeto);
}
```

La clase en donde implemento la interface es esta:

```
public class File implements Interface{

    public void escribir(Object objeto) {
    }

}
```

Suponiendo que hago la instancia un objeto con 1 atributo definido

```
Persona persona = new Persona();
persona.setPersona(0);
```

y luego la implemento en el metodo:

```
Interface prueba = new File();
prueba.escribir(persona);
```

El método `escribir` recibe un objeto **`X` definido** que esta en el programa, mi pregunta es ¿cómo obtengo los atributos del objeto recibido para poder trabajarlos dentro del método, es decir como obtengo sus atributos para usarlos?.

Mi problema es que no puedo obtener los atributos del objeto recibido dentro del método.

¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Si solo puedes manejar un `Object`, entonces puedes acceder a sus atributos mediante el uso de reflection.

Comment: Entonces mejor lo implemento así: tengo la interfaz y esta la implemento en dos o mas clases que contienen el método "escribir", cada clase la uso con un objeto diferente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concreto que necesitas resolver? ¿Para qué necesitas esta interfaz y las implementaciones de ella?

Comment: Creo que si se puede, y si te da algún error entonces tendrías que declarar el tipo de objeto a una nueva variable y le asignas lo que has recibido y así la nueva variable tendrá el mismo contenido del objeto, se me hace muy extraño que no puedas hacerlo.

Comment: Estoy intentando implementar el patrón DAO, quiero recibir un objeto en un método que escribe sus atributos en un archivo, en total son dos objetos que necesito escribir.

Comment: Y no tienes suficiente con usar los getters para recuperar las propiedades del objeto que recibe el método por parametro?

Comment: Lo puedo hacer, simplemente defino el tipo de objeto en el método y accedo a los set y get, pero eso no es lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que tu pregunta es como recibir las propiedades de ese objeto `Persona` cuando se lo pasas como objeto, ¿cierto? Si vas a utilizar el método escribir con más de un objeto como he leído en algún comentario, es correcto pasar el argumento como Objeto, así que yo haría lo siguiente:

Si sabes en todo caso qué tipo de objeto te tiene que pasar, solo necesitarías castearlo:

```
public void escribir(Object objeto) {
    Persona p = (Persona)objeto;
}
```

Si en vez de toda la persona quisieras coger solo una propiedad del objeto sería algo así:

```
public void escribir(Object objeto) {
   String nombre = ((Persona)objeto).getNombre();
    }
```

Y por último, si no tienes claro qué tipo de objeto te pasa el método y quieres comprobarlo podrías hacer algo así:

```
public void escribir(Object objeto) {
    if(objeto instanceof Persona){
       //Ejecutar código de persona
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias,me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola que tal soy nuevo en java y quería saber como mandarias a imprimir este método?? public void escribir(Object objeto) { if(objeto instanceof Persona){ //Ejecutar código de persona } }